# Is it possible to use [ArgumentCompletions()] in a function with no parameters?

Tags: powershell

```
function test{$args}
```

Take a function like the above, when I am providing one or two arguments to it, pressing `tab` should auto complete its parameter arguments, just like functions that make use of `[ArgumentCompletions()]`:

```
function test {
    param(
        [ArgumentCompletions('foo', 'bar')]
        $param
    )
    $param
}
``
```

I tried the following but does not seem to work:

```
function test {[ArgumentCompletions('foo', 'bar')]$args}
```

Comment: `ArgumentCompletions` is an attribute, it only works as a parameter decoration, meaning, no, what you want to do will not work. It requires to be a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need a [`[Parameter()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) attribute with its `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property set to (implied) `$true` in order to define an *explicit* parameter that is the [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)-function equivalent to using the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) in a *simple* function (which is *implicitly* defined).
- You can then apply the [`ArgumentCompletions()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompletionsAttribute) attribute to that explicit parameter.

```bash
function test {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [ArgumentCompletions('foo', 'bar')]
    $AllPositionalArguments
  )
}
```

The above accepts an open-ended number of (positional) arguments, and each tab-completes to `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: Amazing, I  want to wrap common desktop applications and their random Cli args with this basic type of function, until I can get around to fully integrating them one by one. Much better than  Crescendo. Thank you mklement